# Hvplot/bokeh summed Bar chart from Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh, holoviews

I'm trying to print a "simple" Bar chart, using HVPlot and bokeh in jupyter notebook. 
Here is some simplified data:

My Data originally looks like this: 
[image]

My goal is to get a bar chart like That (Note it doesn't have to be stacked. The only importatnt thing are the Totals.):

[image]

Since I couldn't figure out how to get a bar chart with the sum of certain columns, I used `pandas.melt` to model the Data to look like that:

[image]

With this Data I can plot it, but then the values aren't summed. Instead, there are multiple Bars behind each other.
[image]

Here is the code I used to test:

```
 testd = {'Name': ['Item1', 'Item2','Item3','Item3'],'Filter': ['F1','F2','F1','F1'], 
                 'Count': [1,5,2,1], 'CountCategory': ['CountA','CountB','CountA','CountD']}
 testdf = pd.DataFrame(data=testd)
 testdf.hvplot.bar('CountCategory','Count',groupby='Filter', rot=90, aggregator=np.sum)
```

It doesn't change anything if I omit the `aggregator=np.sum`

Does anyone know how to properly plot this? 
It doesn't have to use the "transposed" data since I'm only doing that because I have no idea how to plot the Original Data.
And another question would be if there is a possibility

Answer (score 2):

The `aggregator` is used by the datashade/rasterize operation to aggregate the data and indeed has no effect on bar plots. If you want to aggregate the data I recommend doing so using pandas methods. However in your case I don't think that's the issue, the main problem in implementing the plot you requested is that in holoviews the legend is generally linked to the styling, which means that you can't easily get the legend to display the filter **and** color each bar separately.

You could do this and add the Filter as a hover column, which means you still have access to it:

```
testdf.hvplot.bar('CountCategory', 'Count', by='Name', stacked=True, rot=90, hover_cols=['Filter'])
```

[image: barplot1]

I'll probably raise an issue in HoloViews to support a legend decoupled from the styling.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I should've asked more precisely because my actual dataset is probably going to contain thousands of items. So the Chart doesn't have to be stacked. I actually only care about the totals in each column.